# Pass Ansible template variable from inventory group

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have 2 different server groups in my hosts inventory configuration:

```
[tier1]
server1

[tier2]
server2
```

I need to upload a configuration file (app.conf) into the remote servers, in which I need to set a parameter (environment:) according to the inventory group (tier1 or tier2).

**Playbook**

```
- name: Add node
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  roles:
  - node
```

**Template (app.conf.j2)**

```
  {% if ansible_fqdn in groups['tier1'] %}
  environment: tier1
  {% else %}
  environment: tier2
  {% endif %}
```

**main.yaml snippet**

```
- name: Copy over app.conf configuration file
  template:
    src: app.conf.j2
    dest: /etc/app.conf
```

**Output**

```
changed: [server1]
changed: [server2]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working, as the setup value in app.conf file is "tier2" in both servers...

```
ssh_service:
  enabled: "yes"
  labels:
    environment: ['tier2']
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: It ran correctly on ansible [core 2.13.3]

Comment: Hi @Khaled
Found the issue... It was related to the `ansible_fqdn` fact.
One has "server1" as fqdn name and the second one "server2.com". It seems that Ansible considers only the second one as a fqdn name, that's why it uses it in both servers then.
Changing `ansible_fqdn` to `inventory_hostname` solved the issue!